# Linux Maldetect Not Sending Email Reports

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, sendmail, malware

I've set Linux Malware Detect to send me emails of the reports it generates, but haven't received a single one even though it has produced several reports. Relevant maldet settings /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet include:

```
email_alert="1"
email_addr="my@email.com"
email_ignore_clean="0"
```

I've also used the command:

```
whereis mail
```

to make sure the "mail" command is installed and it returns "/etc/mail" to verify it's installed.

What do I need to do to receive emails from maldet?

Comment: Install the mail command, first.

Comment: Thank you sir, this was the correct answer. In my case, I had to run "sudo yum install mailx -y" to install it. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system doesn't have the `mail` command installed. To resolve the problem, install it. For instance:

```
yum install /usr/bin/mail
```